# remove class jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having two div tags . i like to add class on click event for current div  .
But after that, when i click second div , both the div has the class.
how to remove class for previous div?

```
<div title="a1"></div>

<div title="a1"></div>

$('[title:a1]').click(function() {

   $(this).addClass('current');

});
```

where should i wright remove class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `=` in your [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[title=a1]').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Note, you should use something like `div[title=a1]` instead here...anything to narrow that expensive selector down.

---

To remove the `current` class from the previously selected one, just do this:

```
$('[title=a1]').click(function() {
   $('.current[title=a1]').removeClass('current');
   $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove the class from ALL elements first.

```
  $('div[title=a1]').click(function() {
       $('div[title=a1]').removeClass('current'); //remove current fom all divs
       $(this).addClass('current'); //ad it to current div only
   });
```